# How to display numbers pad when i click the tapestry textfield

Tags: tapestry

What is the way to display numeric number pad in smart phones for phone number field.

Here I searched & found that

type="tel" & type="number" will work out

but in tapestry it shows error :

Unable to resolve 'tel' to a component class name
Unable to resolve 'number' to a component class name

Can anyone please tell me when user comes to & clicks phone number field, number pad needs to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Tapestry are you using?

```
   <t:textfield value="value" placeholder="Number field"
    label="Number field" type="number" />
```

Works fine for me in 5.3.6 and opens up the number keyboard on the iPad.

According to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-1787) bug report, this will only work in 5.3.2 and up, so you may need to upgrade your Tapestry version.

Answer (score 0):

Your error states that tapestry tries to interpit `type="number"` to the tapestry component called "number" which does not exist.

In the tapestry namespace `type` is a reserved attribute to indicate to which component the rendering of the tag with the type="coponentName" should be delegated to.

So I'm assuming your tml snippet will look something like:

```
<t:textfield type="number" value="yourValuePropery" .../>
```

Meaning that type will be read as t:type and thus causing your exception.

You can fix this by using the following in stead:

Your *.tml

```
<input t:id="myNumberField" type="number"/>
```

Your *.java

```
@Component(id="myNumberField", parameters={"value=yourValuePropery"})
private TextField myNumberField;
```